# Sending list of emails to a user once they sign up in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, scheduled-tasks

I need to send emails to the user who sign up on my system. So, for instance say a user sign up today then after 3 days they should receive one email. Then after 6 days he should receive another email and so forth. There are 8 emails with the interval of 3 days.

I need to run a task where every midnight or every 12 hrs  and that task should check whether are there any user who created account in 3,6,9,etc days before. I am aware of Rufus-Scheduler and even it works fine but I am not sure it is good to use it as my production configuration is unicorn and ngninx.I am also using sidekiq in my application for devise async emails.

Is there any other way to implement this or what would be the best way to implement such a system. Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best recommendation would be:

1. sign up for an account on mailchimp
2. add the relevant mailchimp gem to your app
3. when a user signs up to your app, send an API request to mailchimp to subscribe the user
4. on mailchimp, set up a campaign that has the emails for the user at the required frequency...
5. don't forget to unsub the user from mailchimp if your user deletes their account on your app

Use mailchimp because you'll get better visibility on open/close rates and it will automatically deal with things like the user wanting to un-sub from your emails (which you are required by law to allow them to do). You also get better ability to do nice things with filtering the list of users eg sending a special email to users that have not yet seen the X email or who opened every email...

Comment: I am having mailchimp already installed and I am using it but then how I should automate the process of all those emails which I need to send them, as my emails will trigger on created_at value

Comment: You can set up campaigns that are triggered on "x days after a person joins the list". You should look at the mailchimp doco for how to go about doing that (or ask their support) :)

Comment: I also recommend different emails for "X days after they joined and they've done Important Thing X on your site (eg purchased a product)" vs "X days after they joined and they've done nothing on your site yet" - but that would require you to also set up a Mailchimp API call that updates the personal information of a subscriber when they do Thing X

Comment: in my case it simple, I need to send them campaign emails every 3 days based on their date. So for instance user A sign in today say Sept 5, then on sept 8 he should automatically receive email then sept 11 he should receive another email. For other user who sign up on Sept 6 he should receive email on sept 9 then sept 12 and so on

Comment: So you mean mailchimp provides this kind of feature?

Comment: Yes as standard :) So much easier than writing your own, and better analytics too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use reschedule method of sidekiq

Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.find_job().reschedule(1.day.from_now)

Comment: and where I should call this process ?

Comment: First Send signup email and then reschedule a job to send emails after 3, 6, 9 days as per your logic